# Discord.js | Mentioning someone in an embed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey im trying to make a bot which has hug commands and its meant to  say you hugged a user that you mentioned, inside an embed with a random hug image...Code:

```
if (message.content === '+hug'){
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    let maxImageNumber = 5;
let imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (maxImageNumber - 1 + 1)) + 1;
let imageName = `${imageNumber}.gif`
let imagePath = `./hug/${imageName}`

let file = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imagePath);
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embed.setDescription(message.author.username + ' *just hugged* '+ user.username);
    embed.setImage(`attachment://${imageName}`)
    embed.setColor(0xffe6f7)
message.channel.send({ files: [file], embed: embed });
  }
```

**The Error is every time I do the command nothing shows up**

How would I solve this issue?

*I already made a question like this but it wasn't clear enough, I hope this is clear*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current doesn't work, because you check if the content of the message is equal to `+hug`. So when you send `+hug @some-user`, the content of the message is not equal to `+hug`anymore. The following code will work:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith('+hug')){
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    let maxImageNumber = 5;
let imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (maxImageNumber - 1 + 1)) + 1;
let imageName = `${imageNumber}.gif`
let imagePath = `./hug/${imageName}`

let file = new Discord.MessageAttachment(imagePath);
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embed.setDescription(message.author.username + ' *just hugged* '+ user.username);
    embed.setImage(`attachment://${imageName}`)
    embed.setColor(0xffe6f7)
message.channel.send({ files: [file], embed: embed });
  }
```

It doesn't check if the content of the message is equal to something but if **it starts** with something.

Comment: Yes it worked but the only issue now is that the gif(image) is separated with the embed, in other words the image is out of the embed but the embed still says "Azrael just hugged {user}"

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`` embed.setDescription(`${message.author.username} *just hugged* ${user.username}`); ``

If you want to **mention** the second person you just type `user` instead of `user.username`

Hope this helped